# Extracting numbers from the string using regex

Tags: c, regex, string

I am trying to extract the number `4` and `3` from the string `/ab/cd__my__sep__4__some__sep__3`. I am trying with regex but not sure how would I do this. I wrote the following code, but it just prints out `__my__sep__4__some__sep__3`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* s = "/ab/cd__my__sep__4__some__sep__3";
    regex_t regex;
    int reti = regcomp(&regex,"__my__sep__([0-9]+)",REG_EXTENDED);
    if(reti!=0) {
        exit(-1);
    }else {
        regmatch_t match[2];
        reti = regexec(&regex, s, 2, match, 0);
        if(reti == 0) {
            char *v = &s[match[1].rm_so];
            ssize_t fl;
            sscanf(v, "%zu", &fl);
            printf("%s",v);
        }else {
            printf("else");
        }
    }
}
```

How could I extract the numbers `4` and `3` ?

Comment: Can you walk all the string (possibly backwards) with `isdigit()` instead?

Comment: Why would you want to extract 3 here? It doesn't appear after `__my__sep__`, so the regex should reject it. Do you just want any number that appears after `__my__sep__` or all numbers in the string? In either case, I think regex is overkill for this problem. You can get a pointer to `__my__sep__` with `strstr` and then walk forward to collect the next digit run. Or, if you want digits in the string, it's just a matter of writing a loop and tossing in a conditional. Thanks for clarifying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match[0]` refers to the part of the text matched by the entire pattern. `match[1]` is the match corresponding to the first capture (parenthesized subpattern).

Note that `&s[match[1].rm_so]` gives you a pointer to the start of the capture, but if you print the string at that point, you will get the part of the string starting at the beginning of the capture. In this case, that doesn't really matter. Since you're using `sscanf` to extract the integer value of the captured text, the fact that the substring isn't terminated immediately doesn't matter; it's not going to be followed by a digit, and `sscanf` will stop at the first non-digit.

But in the general case, it's possible that it will not be so easy to identify the end of the matched capture, and you can use one of these techniques:

If you want to print the capture, you can use a computed string width format: (See Note 1.)

```
printf("%.*s\n", match[1].rm_eo - match[1].rm_so, &s[match[1].rm_so]);
```

If you have `strndup`, you can easily create a dynamically-allocated copy of the capture: (See Note 2.)

```
char* capture = strndup(&s[match[1].rm_so], match[1].rm_eo - match[1].rm_so);
```

As a quick-and-dirty hack, it is also possible to just insert a NUL terminator (assuming that the searched string is not immutable, which means that it cannot be a string literal). You'll probably want to save the old value of the following character so that you can restore the string to it's original state:

```
char* capture = &s[match[1].rm_so];
char* rest = &s[match[1].rm_eo];
char saved_char = *rest;
*rest = 0;
/* capture now points to a NUL-terminated string. */
/* ... */
/* restore s */
*rest = saved_char;
```

None of the above is really necessary in the context of the original question, since the `sscanf` as written will work perfectly if you change the start of the string to scan from `match[0]` to `match[1]`.

#### Notes:

1. In the general case, you should test to make sure that a capture was actually found before trying to use its offset. The `rm_so` member will be -1 if the capture was not found during the regex search That doesn't necessarily mean that the search failed, because the capture could be part of an alternative not used in the match.
2. Don't forget to free the copy when you no longer need it. If you don't have `strndup`, it's pretty easy to implement. But watch out for the corner cases.

Comment: also the op is printing the `string` starting from the `start_offset` of the first match. i.e printing the rest of the string until `null termination`.

Comment: `match[1]` prints `4__some__sep__3`

Comment: Is there also a way I can get the `path`? Just the `/ab/cd`?

Comment: @Amanda: The path is the part of the string up to (but not including) index `match[0].rm_so`, right? So if the match succeeds, you could use eg. `strndup(s, match[0].rm_so)` to make a copy of that prefix. (That's part of the reason that `regexec` returns the indices of the start and the end of the total match.)

Comment: Alright. I might have 2 more numbers in the string. So it could become `/ab/cd,4,3,10,11`. So now `strndup(&s[match[1].rm_so], match[1].rm_eo - match[1].rm_so);` gives me `4` and `&s[match[1].rm_eo];` wil give me `,3,10,11`. Is there a way I could get all the numbers separately?

Comment: I tried multiple capture group `,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)` but `match[2]` does not work. It gives segmentation fault.

Comment: @Amanda: did you remember to change `regmatch_t match[2];`? and the third argument of `regexec(&regex, s, 2, match, 0);`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `sscanf()`, there is no need to use a *regex*. You can parse the two numbers from your string using `sscanf()` alone using the format string: `"%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d"` where `"%*[^0-9]"` uses the assignment suppression `'*'` to read and discard all non-digit characters and then uses `"%d"` to extract the integer value. The full *format-string* just repeats those two patterns twice.

A short example using your input could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *s = "/ab/cd__my__sep__4__some__sep__3";
    int a, b;

    if (sscanf (s, "%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d", &a, &b) == 2)
        printf ("a: %d\nb: %d\n", a, b);
    else {
        fputs ("error: parse of integers failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/parse2ints
a: 4
b: 3
```

If you find yourself attempting to parse something that `sscanf()` cannot handle, then a *regex* is appropriate. Here, `sscanf()` is more than capable of handling your needs alone.

Comment: The path could have numbers too. It will fail in those cases.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, That wasn't stated, but certainly will cause problems. In that case you will need a regex to anchor the match of the two numbers to the last path component.

Answer (score -2):

Create a regex format that only holds [0-9]. Then create a separate boolean function checking whether a character belongs or not to your regex. Then apply the function to your string. If true, add the character to the string you want to output

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should consider adding the code that illustrates your answer.